# Higher homotopy local systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, local-systems

The concept of a local system in algebraic geometry is often described as a locally constant constructible sheaf on a scheme $X$, which is in essence a sheaf whose stalk at a point $x$ comes equipped with an action of $\pi_1(X,x)$, where the fundamental group's definition is implicit in the category of local systems we are working on.

I guess that it is possible to consider, similarly, a sheaf whose stalks come equipped with an action of an abstract group, or perhaps a higher homotopy group $\pi_k(X,x)$. For some $k$. For whatever reason, I never encountered the latter in my studies. Are they important? Are they used somewhere in the literature?

Sorry for the vague question.

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of [one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/356749) [of these](https://mathoverflow.net/q/360726) [earlier](https://mathoverflow.net/q/106896) [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/403734)?

Answer (score 5):

Infinity local systems have been defined and studied by various people. For instance, Lurie gives the following definition in some notes *Algebraic K-theory and Manifold Topology, notes for course Math 281*

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-category. A *local system* on $X$ with values in $\mathcal{C}$ is a map of simplicial sets,
$$Sing(X)\to \mathcal{C}.$$
The collection of all local systems on $X$ with values in $\mathcal{C}$ then gives an $\infty$-category, $Fun(Sing(X),\mathcal{C})$.

Of course, this requires some background reading on $\infty$-categories.  It is also easy to generalise this by replacing the $\infty$-groupoid, $Sing(X)$ by that of smooth singular simplices or a triangulation of $X$. There is some interesting material also in *The higher Riemann-Hilbert correspondence and principal 2-bundles by Camilo Arias Abad and Sebastian Velez Vasquez*, and *A Riemann–Hilbert correspondence for infinity local systems* by
Jonathan Block and Aaron M. Smith (which is on the ArXiv).

There are ways of extending these topological constructions to an algebraic geometry setting, but I do not have the precise references with me.

Elsewhere a link with constructible sheaves, etc, has been explored following ideas on stratified spaces following ideas of Treumann, *Exit paths and constructible stacks. Compos. Math. 145 (2009), no. 6, 1504–1532.* That also leads to other very interesting constructions and generalisations, but I will not try to explain them here, unless that is of interest to someone as it does seem a bit further from the Alg. Geom context.

Comment: Local systems on $X$ can also be identified with locally constant sheaves of spectra on $X$; naive $\Omega X$ spectra; and $\Sigma^\infty_+ \Omega X$ modules. I think each point of view has its advantages, so best to consider them all together.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Is that the same as the definition in this answer? I suspect that you need something like $X$ has singular shape?

Comment: @Z.M I'm assuming $X$ is a CW complex here, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Z.M See in Luries L-Theory Notes (https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/287xnotes/Lecture21.pdf) or this paper on Morita Cohomology (https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1327) for a reference.

Comment: @MarkusZetto As Connor Malin said above, it only applies to good spaces (although now I am not sure whether being of singular shape is enough, it is enough to assume to be locally of singular shape instead, cf. Higher Algebra, the paragraph before Cons A.4.17).

Comment: The point about nice spaces / CW spaces is, of course, correct. For other more general spaces (as for extra structure such as schemes etc.) one need to use hypercoverings, or strong shape methods., but much of the theory has its analogue in that setting as well.

Comment: @Connor Malin The most general case of infinity local systems may not be modelled by spectra.  The point of the actual definition given by Lurie is that the definition requires just an $\infty$-category in which to take values and not some sort of stable setting, although, if I remember rightly, that spectral case is the most important in his notes.

Comment: @Z. M.  (Really an aside) There is a sense in which 'singular shape' is not a good term. Shape theory à la Borsuk, handles spaces and other structures such as toposes which are allowed to be very singular in the sense of having singularities of various kinds topological, algebraic, etc. The sense in which the term has come to be used seems to mean almost the exact opposite. For example, the Warsaw circle has the Borsuk shape of a circle, but not the same shape as its singular complex. Should it be conisdered to be a singular shape or not?